# Pygame from console with PiTFT

Tags: python, raspbian-wheezy, touchscreen, pitft

I wrote a simple script that uses pygame to display the information. However, I found that it won't display on screen when I call it from terminal through SSH. I found this [guide/solution](http://learn.adafruit.com/pi-video-output-using-pygame/pointing-pygame-to-the-framebuffer) on adafruit, but it apparently doesn't work. `sudo python pyscope.py` does not give me red box on the screen. From console, doing `startx &` followed by `sudo python pyscope.py` doesnt work either.

Is there another way to display a pygame window onto the [PiTFT](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1601) from console?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whichy display are you using to display your graphics? I believe that display 0 is the HDMI output on the Pi.

You'll need to tell pygame to use the TFT:

```
os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb1"
```

You can directly call pygame.init() after this. No need to deal with different drivers etc. etc.

Comment: Well well well... you have earned a lot of reputation in 2 days.  Keep up the good work.